# What is the meaning of Quatschkopp or Quatschkopf

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure how it is pronounced correctly but what is the meaning of Quatschkopp or Quatschkopf?

Is it something nice to say?

Comment: Relevant to the pp/pf question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyer_line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mild derogative to say about or to someone who says wrong or unpopular things and stuff you don't like personally.

The "roughness" of it depends on the context. You can say that to your friend if she tells you some unbelievable story, or if you want to refuse a compliment in a playful way, and that friend probably won't take much offense.

But if you say that publicly to your rival in parliament after his big talking point, that might make its way into national newspapers.

So on average, it's not a nice thing to say, but it's not a swearword in the traditional sense.

The Kopp variant is a dialect version of the Kopf variant, as has been mentioned already.

Pronounciation of the standard variant would be ['kvaʧ,kɔpf]. Take a look at wiktionary for pronounciation questions. It carries IPA transcriptions for lots of words.

Answer (score 2):

In before: Quatschkopf is the dialect-free pronunciation of the word. It describes someone talking either too much or just false stuff. Some may also say it describes a person who acts unreasonable in general. Even though the description may not sound like it the word is not what I would call a swearword.